# SQL Where in to Linq with DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to achieve this in c#

```
Select a.Name,a.Param
from Customization a
where a.name in (select Name from Standard)
```

I have try something like this but it still doesn't work.

```
 merge = dt1.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name")
            .Contains(dt2.Rows.Contains("Name")))
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: what are dt1 and dt2? How are they structured?

Comment: Dt1 and Dt2 are data tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the current way we need to get the name list from the second data-table(`dt2`) for each row in `dt1` so I suggest you get the list of names first and then check whether `r.Field<string>("Name")` contains in the collection. For this, you can use the following code

```
var NameCollection = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();

merge = dt1.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => NameCollection.Contains(r.Field<string>("Name")))
           .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: i'll accept it once the cooldown timer for accepting has off. Once again thank you very much !